# Dynamical system pendulum interpretation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

Consider the motion of a simple pendulum as a 2nd-order ODE:

$\ddot{\theta} + \frac{g}{l} \sin \theta =0 $.

I can write this as a coupled system of first-order equations as:

$\dot{\theta} = u$,

$\dot{u} = -\frac{g}{l}\sin \theta$.

I have seen several definitions/derivations online and in textbooks where they authors say that the phase space of this system is given by a manifold which is a cylinder. I don't understand. Isn't the phase space of this system just $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ where the state vector is given by $\left[\theta, u\right] \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Thanks.
Thomas

Comment: See Physics SE: [Why is the phase space of a simple pendulum defined on a cylinder and not $^2$?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285295/why-is-the-phase-space-of-a-simple-pendulum-defined-on-a-cylinder-and-not-math)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that vector field you have constructed is $2 \pi$ periodic in $\theta$ so it makes sense to consider this variable as being on the circle $S^1$, this has the benefit of making these trajectories closed.

So for example here is the phase space with level curves of the Hamiltonian in your original coordinates along with several highlighted trajectories, note in particular how the red curve seems to run off to infinity: [image]

Now lets take the position variable $\theta$ and map it onto the circle and so the image of the trajectories look like this[image]

Which seems to fit better with the fact that the angle variable is $2\pi$-periodic, all of the trajectories are now closed curves on the cylinder.

Comment: Hi. Wow! Thanks for that very insightful answer. It is much appreciated. A quick question, though: So, is taking a cylinder topology here simply a neat result, that has a very powerful interpretation, or are the $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R} \times S^{1}$ cases identical?

Comment: What do you mean by identical exactly? So to solve the ode for example  I constructed the solutions in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then mapped the solution on to the cylinder - there is nothing wrong with taking the phase space to be $\mathbb{R}^2$ but adopting the "cylinder topology" viewpoint enforces the idea that a pendulum at an angle $\theta$ and a pendulum at an angle $\theta + 2 \pi$ is really just a pendulum at the same angle.

Comment: Hi. Okay, that is much clearer now, thanks!

Comment: Please can you tell me how I can plot this Hamiltonian mr @Thomas Moore.